# Ошибка fatal: repository not found после создания репозитория на удалённом HTTPS сервере

Tags: git, https

Создал новый репозиторий на удалённом HTTPS сервере:

```
  $ mkdir test.git; cd test.git/;  git init --bare
```

На сервере уже есть несколько репозиториев и конфигурация не менялась.

Пробую клонировать новый и, для сравнения, уже существующий репозитории:

```
$ git clone https://server-url/git/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: repository 'https://server-url/git/test.git/' not found

$ git clone https://server-url/git/default.git
Cloning into 'default'...
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Что я не так сделал?

Найденные ответы, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947059/git-clone-repository-not-found), [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337199/remote-repository-not-found-fatal-not-found) или [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813568/git-remote-repository-not-found) пока не
помогли.

Comment: было бы очень удивительно, если бы заработало. что навело вас на мысль, что проделанные вами действия «приведут к успеху»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin   Пока всё работало. А что не хватает?

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что «добавляли вы добавляли хранилища, а на очередном вдруг раз и перестало работать»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо за подсказку,  вспомнил,  чего не хватает.  Дайте ответ,  если не затруднит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для новых репозиториев надо после команды `git init --bare` выполнить:

```
mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
git update-server-info
```

Без этого доступ на новый репозиторий не будет работать, что можно увидеть в логах:

```
"GET /git/test.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 404 516 "-" "git/2.8.3"
```

Уже существующие репозитории, упомянутые в вопросе, были перенесены на сервер как минимум с одним коммитом.

См. подглаву *Dumb HTTP* в 
[Git-book 4.1](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).